# Is the sudden appearance of transient random walks in 3-dimensions a phase transition?

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Consider a particle walking uniformly at random on the infinite d-dimensional lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$. This is symmetric random walk.

Symmetric random walk in two dimensions almost always returns to its starting point.

But in dimensions greater than three this is no longer true.

**Is this an example of a first order phase transition as the dimension $d$ goes from $2$ to $3$?**

My concern is about the definition of a phase transition in this sort of dynamical system. Is there a discontinuous jump in the number of recurrent walks? Yes. So I imagine this is a first order phase transition. But no one ever mentions this so I need to be corrected or told "its obviously a phase transition".

Also, for something this simple and yet characteristic of deeper behaviour in other systems, does anyone know of, perhaps, the next twist in the tale?

Comment: I'm not sure this question entirely makes sense unless you can create some sort of continuous parametrization that gets you between $d=2$ and $d=3$. In particular, the situation as stated is really not discontinuous, because the natural numbers have the discrete topology.

Comment: So you can't have a first order phase transition in this sort of system unless you 'inject' some sort of continuous variable?

Comment: I think so. Otherwise what does "discontinuity" mean?

Comment: Your "i.e." is wrong. That the walk almost surely returns to the origin is a stronger statement than that there are infinitely many recurrent walks.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: Come to think of it, the other "i.e." is even wronger: In three dimensions there are also infinitely many recurrent walks. Since the probability of recurrence here is not $1$, that also illustrates that the probability of recurrence being $1$ can't be equivalent to there being infinitely many recurrent walks.

Comment: And now you seem to embark us onto a quite different question...

Comment: It is a side question addressing the concern of joriki

Comment: Sure. What is your question already?